# I Have my ADT version 23 how to change ADT in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

*I have downloaded my new ADT version 23 
*When i open my eclipse it still opens with ADT version 22 how to change the path??

Comment: Help > Check for updates

Comment: It shows no updates found

Comment: you have more than one sdks in your machine?

Comment: i have downloaded from net but dono how to insert that ADT by replacing ADT version 22

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that ADT version 22 is successfully uninstalled. 
and you should change the old sdk location to new sdk location in

windows > preference > android > sdk location

Comment: how to uninstall it ??
when i goto help->about ADT i cant found uninstall option???

Comment: just delete the folder of old ADT.and set the sdk location of new ADT in windows > preference > android > sdk location